# Can any method crawl a infinite scrolling web in python without selenium?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, infinite-scroll

I want to crawl web page like quora, pinterest, etc. I found all examples using selenium to simulate scrolling action, yet open a new window for scrolling and crawling is slow and inefficient. Is Any method for crawling an infinite scrolling page more efficient?

Answer (score 1):

If the website uses Ajax frame to transfer data, my answer could help you. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34802775/5246180

Comment: I've tried your method, but it can't be done in Quora. Can you show me more detail about how you did in Quora?

Comment: It works on Quora but firstly you need to log in on Quora. Or it won't work.